# Weird behaviour in navigation with TabBar over non-adjacent tabs

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs

I am experiencing a weird behaviour when navigating between TabBar tabs; I have 8 tabs in total.

If I navigate(tapping or swiping) between the tabs:

**tab1 -> tab2 -> tab3 -> tab4 -> tab5 -> tab6 -> tab7 -> tab8** in a sequence then it works as intended.

However, if during the navigation I skip adjacent tabs, and go to tab4 directly from tab1 for example like the following:

tab1 -> tab4 or Tab6 -> Tab2 then a weird behaviour occurs, and a different tab or state is loaded instead.

I have two classes, ExploreList which contains the tabs and it calls the NewsStream objects. Here is the code:

```
class ExploreList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => ExploreListState();
}

class ExploreListState extends State<ExploreList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {});
    scrollControllerExploreList = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 84);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollControllerExploreList.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {});
return DefaultTabController(
      length: 8,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Top Headlines')

          bottom: const TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'World'),
              Tab(text: 'Nation'),
              Tab(text: 'Business'),
              Tab(text: 'Entertainment'),
              Tab(text: 'Health'),
              Tab(text: 'Science'),
              Tab(text: 'Sports'),
              Tab(text: 'Technology'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          bottom: false,
          child: TabBarView(
            children: [
              NewsStream("world"),
              NewsStream("nation"),
              NewsStream("business"),
              NewsStream("entertainment"),
              NewsStream("health"),
              NewsStream("science"),
              NewsStream("sports"),
              NewsStream("technology"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

And this the NewsStream Class containing the bloc:

```
ScrollController scrollControllerNewsStream;

class NewsStream extends StatefulWidget {

  final String topic;

  const NewsStream(this.topic);

  @override
  createState() => NewsStreamState();
}

class NewsStreamState extends State<NewsStream> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {});
    scrollControllerNewsStream = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 84);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollControllerNewsStream.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bloc.fetchExploreNews(widget.topic);
    setState(() {}); 
    return SafeArea(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        controller: scrollControllerNewsStream,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(

          ),

          streamBuild(bloc.exploreNews),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, besides your scrollControllerExploreList variable not declared and the missing comma after your appBar title, I couldn't reproduce this behavior your talked about, everything worked well here.

Comment: sorry for the unintended code error. I am using flutter v1.12.13+hotfix.8 and apparently this is an issue that was mentioned here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/34948